# Get array from within an array from URL

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm trying to extract the "stops" array from the JSON Array, but it's contained within another array called "results". How do I get the "stops" and put them into a JSON array?

The variables have been declared further up the code (not shown). There is also catches (not shown).

The code is giving me the error is:

```
2018-12-19 14:31:38.892 6650-6787/ie.[college].student.[studentid].dublinbuses E/StopIdResultsActivity: An error occurred! Error: No value for stops.
```

The part of code I need looked at is:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ...
            ...
                try {

                    origin = "";
                    destination = "";
                    route_result = "";

                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(routeid_jsonStr);

                    ...

                    }
                    else {
                    JSONArray results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

                     //looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject r = results.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONArray stops = jsonObj.getJSONArray("stops");
                        for (int j = 0; j < stops.length(); j++) {

                            JSONObject s = stops.getJSONObject(j);

                            stopid = r.getString("stopid");
                            shortname = r.getString("shortname");
                            shortnamelocalized = r.getString("shortnamelocalized");

                            HashMap<String, String> stop = new HashMap<>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            stop.put("stopid", stopid);
                            stop.put("shortname", shortname);
                            stop.put("shortnamelocalized", shortnamelocalized );

                            resultList.add(stop);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Examples:
[JSON](https://data.smartdublin.ie/cgi-bin/rtpi/routeinformation?routeid=77a&operator=bac&format=json) OR [XML](https://data.smartdublin.ie/cgi-bin/rtpi/routeinformation?routeid=77a&operator=bac&format=xml)

```
{
errorcode: "0",
errormessage: "",
numberofresults: 4,
route: "77a",
timestamp: "19/12/2018 13:03:06",
results: [
{
operator: "bac",
origin: "Citywest",
originlocalized: "Iarthar na Cathrach ",
destination: "Ringsend",
destinationlocalized: "",
lastupdated: "27/06/2016 09:02:52",
stops: [
    {
    stopid: "1358",
    displaystopid: "1358",
    shortname: "Dame Street",
    shortnamelocalized: "Sráid an Dáma",
    fullname: "Dame Street",
    fullnamelocalized: "",
    latitude: "53.34430611",
    longitude: "-6.262861111",
    operators: [
        {
        name: "bac",
        routes: [
                "77A"
                ]
        }
    ]
},

...
...
```

Comment: Please add a clear problem statement to your question.  Note that a good explanation can sometimes be more useful than a bunch of code.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: have you tried turning `JSONArray stops = jsonObj.getJSONArray("stops");`  into `JSONArray stops = r.getJSONArray("stops");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look on these lines:

```
JSONObject r = results.getJSONObject(i);
JSONArray stops = jsonObj.getJSONArray("stops");
```

I think it should be instead:

```
JSONObject r = results.getJSONObject(i);
JSONArray stops = r.getJSONArray("stops");
```

And here you also mix up varialbles:

```
stopid = r.getString("stopid");
shortname = r.getString("shortname");
shortnamelocalized = r.getString("shortnamelocalized");
```

It should be:

```
stopid = s.getString("stopid");
shortname = s.getString("shortname");
shortnamelocalized = s.getString("shortnamelocalized");
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm thinking. Otherwise, you're just going back to your beginning object trying to access the inner array from the outermost layer.

Comment: Ok, that stops the error message, but it doesn't set the variables `stop.put(...)`

Comment: I think the problem with `stop.put(...)` is somewhere else. Please check the variables `stopid`, `shortname` and `shortnamelocalized` and see if they contain correct values.

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you use two different variables

```
JSONObject s = stops.getJSONObject(j);

stopid = r.getString("stopid");
shortname = r.getString("shortname");
```

You store the json `stop` data in `s`but reads it from `r`, so it should be

```
JSONObject s = stops.getJSONObject(j);

stopid = s.getString("stopid");
shortname = s.getString("shortname");
```

Comment: Then what is `r`?

Comment: The "results" array. The "stops" array is contained within the "results".